# Geocoding using ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, geocoding

[image]

i want to add a geocode service for roads in Ivory coast ,,, i just have the names of places (no ZIP code) ! it works on arcmap but on it doasn't work on the server !

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you attempted to submit your request with return fields as: * ?